# Update a value for each document inside an array of a collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB Collection with objects of type:

```
{
  id: 1223
  items: [{
    length: 12.233333,
  }, {
    length: 4.2323232323232,
  }]
}
```

How can I update the `length` of each item by rounding to 2 decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         items: {
            $map: {
               input: "$items",
               in: { length: { $round: ["$$this.length", 2] } }
            }
         }
      }
   }
]);
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tr1_zEfBWoX)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$round` operator like this:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "items": {
        $map: {
          input: "$items",
          as: "item",
          in: {
            length: {
              $round: [
                "$$item.length",
                2
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LYfvmDTHpZ1)